# for loop displaying my data twice in a table

Tags: java, android-studio

```
  for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(j);

                            mdate1 = c.getString("date");
                            mshift = c.getString("shift");
                            mqty1 = c.getString("noof_ltrs");
                            mfat1 = c.getString("fat");
                            mrate1 = c.getString("amt_ltrs");
                            mtamt1 = c.getString("total_amount");
                            msts1 = c.getString("Status");



                            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
                            TextView t1v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t1v.setText( mdate1);
                            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t1v);
                            TextView t2v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t2v.setText(mshift);
                            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t2v);
                            TextView t3v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t3v.setText(mqty1);
                            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t3v);
                            TextView t4v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t4v.setText(mfat1);
                            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t4v);
                            TextView t5v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t5v.setText(mrate1);
                            t5v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t5v);
                            TextView t6v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t6v.setText(mtamt1);
                            t6v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t6v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t6v);
                            TextView t7v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t7v.setText(msts1);
                            t7v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t7v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t7v);
                            stk1.addView(tbrow);
}
```

**This is where i generate a dynamic table and read the url and display my data to the table and here is my problem where the for loop is making my table to display the data twice**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY71o.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible the code that runs this loop is being called twice?

Comment: Have you removed all views before running for loop? because its possible if old added views are there and for loop again add that views. Make sure old views removes before add new. And one suggestion must use "RecyclerView" for this type list.

Answer (score 0):

Does the source of JSON itself have distinct data? You should check the JSON whether there is duplicated data or not.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Please add it in comment not answer. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
 you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, 
 provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: sadly, I can't add comment on the question

Comment: well yes i have checked with that i think so there is no duplicated data or anything just wrong with the loop i think, correct me if I'm wrong . If can ill edit my question for further code.

Answer (score 0):

**My further code from a method is like**

```
    public void  loadProducts(final String idss) {

    String y=url+idss;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, y+"&Month="+m2,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                //String shift = "";

                String mdate1 = "0";
                String mqty1 = "0";
                String mfat1 = "0";
                String mrate1 = "0";
                String mtamt1 = "0";
                String msts1 = "0";
                String mshift = "0";



                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {


                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);



                        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(j);

                            mdate1 = c.getString("date");
                            mshift = c.getString("shift");
                            mqty1 = c.getString("noof_ltrs");
                            mfat1 = c.getString("fat");
                            mrate1 = c.getString("amt_ltrs");
                            mtamt1 = c.getString("total_amount");
                            msts1 = c.getString("Status");



                            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
                            TextView t1v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t1v.setText( mdate1);
                            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t1v);
                            TextView t2v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t2v.setText(mshift);
                            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t2v);
                            TextView t3v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t3v.setText(mqty1);
                            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t3v);
                            TextView t4v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t4v.setText(mfat1);
                            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t4v);
                            TextView t5v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t5v.setText(mrate1);
                            t5v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t5v);
                            TextView t6v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t6v.setText(mtamt1);
                            t6v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t6v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t6v);
                            TextView t7v = new TextView(getContext());
                            t7v.setText(msts1);
                            t7v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            t7v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tbrow.addView(t7v);
                            stk1.addView(tbrow);




                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("error", "onResponse: " + e);
                    }


            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            });


    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);


}
```

[then this will be my Jason response from URL i don't think the data is repeated too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI7Yw.png)

Comment: Welcome to _Stack Overflow!_ It would be better if you clarify your question further by edit & combine this into your own post, rather than post it here which is not appropriate as an answer. Besides, formatting improvement would be helpful for other users to go through your question. Regards.